# How can I indicate negative values in different colour in shiny with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to display plot of a data frame which includes negative values either. In this case, the negative values may be indicated with red line. However I couldn't succeed. When try to draw the plot, the negatives values began to follow sequence because of cbind argument. In addition, I don't know another way to combine the data frames.

```
set.seed(123)
tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:10, quantity = round(runif(10, -15, 25)) )

neg <- tmp$quantity[tmp$quantity <0]
tmp.pred <-  cbind(tmp,neg)

y <- ggplot(tmp, aes(time, quantity)) + 
 geom_line() +   
 geom_line(data=tmp.pred, aes(y=neg),color="red") 
 y
```

[image]

Comment: your code gives me an error, don't you get that?

Comment: ggplot2 package should be installed.

Comment: @rawr is right, there is something wrong with your code. for one thing tmp1 <-  cbind.data.frame(tmp,neg) is not working

Comment: I dont know why it doesn't work for you? :/

Comment: restart with a clean r session and try the code in your question only

Comment: `neg` is not a `data.frame`, and it doesn't have the correct number of 'rows'

Comment: I edited the code and image. And cbind.data.frame is cbind now.

Comment: maybe a bit long to do but geom_segment() would help you to get what you want.

Comment: a starting point: `ggplot(tmp, aes(time, quantity, colour=(quantity <= 0))) + geom_line(aes(group=1))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of methods I think get you close to what you're after.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:10, quantity = round(runif(10, -15, 25)) )
```

**method 1** - colour line by expression

This will colour the line from the point the quantity is negative, until the time the quantity is non-negative again.

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(time, quantity, colour=(quantity <= 0))) + 
geom_line(aes(group=1))
```

[image]

**Method 2** - adding an extra column to so we can colour two lines, one is the complete 'quantity' column, and the other is only those values that are negative, or either size of a negative. (otherwise they'll be NA)

```
library(dplyr)
tmp <- tmp %>%
    mutate(neg = ifelse(quantity <= 0, quantity, NA)) %>%
    mutate(neg = ifelse(is.na(neg) & lag(neg) <= 0, quantity, neg)) %>%
    mutate(neg = ifelse(is.na(neg) & lead(neg) <= 0, quantity, neg))

ggplot() +
    geom_line(data=tmp, aes(x=time, y=quantity) , colour="black") +
    geom_line(data=tmp, aes(x=time, y=neg), colour="red")
```

[image]

If you want it to only change colour when the line crosses the `x==0` line you may have to manipulate the data a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:10, quantity = round(runif(10, -15, 25)) )
tmp$series <- ifelse(tmp$quantity < 0, "Negative", "Positive")
y <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x = time, y = quantity, colour = series)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
y
```

Comment: to be honest, it is not exacly what i want. I dont want to see another line for negative values. When the value of the tmp is lower than zero, the colour of line should be changed in order to "warn" or take user attention.